Use after move in function call
When exactly does an object cast with std::moved get moved?
For instance, does the following code constitute use after move?
f(std::move(a), a.Something())

Where f = f(A a, int x) and a is an instance of some class.
I understand that std::move(a) may be evaluated before or after a.Something(), but (since std::move is just a cast) when does the actual move occur?

std::move doesn't really move anything, just casts to an rvalue ref that can trigger calling a relevant overload of f. So it depends on f.

It depends of f signature

With f(A, B), you might have use after move, with f(A&&, B), you are ok.

@Jarod42 Wow, thanks, that just raises more questions! (but it answers this one!)

@wohlstad a.Something() is evaluated before f() is entered, yes. But the order of evaluation of parameters is not fixed, and if the 1st A parameter is passed by value then the construction of the A object can move a's data before a.Something() is evaluated.

@RemyLebeau thanks, I see that now. So the move can occur when the copy into the A a parameter is done.

@wohlstad yes, exactly

Does your f look anything like f(A&& a), and does it take ownership of a? (e.g. move from it). It is important you show a fully minimal reproducible example of the problem you have a question about

As a side note, just today, I needed something akin to *(t++)=func(*t). Since I wasn't sure whether to put the ++ on the left or the right, or whether there even IS a correct solution, I figured regardless of the correct solution, if I'm asking this question, then other people reading this line would too. So, I decided to just write it as *t=func(*t); t++; to make it obvious to everyone. When optimization is enabled, the compiler would compile this and the correct "shorter" version into the same code anyway. In other words: don't bother, and split up things so it's easier to read.

Seems to me that code is UB - there's no guarantee in which order the parameters to f will be evaluated

@catnip: UB has special meaning (anything can happens). Here it is "just" the order of evaluation which is not predictable (which might lead to unexpected result), no UB per s.e.

@ChristianStieber: Even without optimization, both generated code would be identical.

@Jarod42 So 'implementation defined'?  This is a terrible practise, whatever you call it.

Neither implementation defined ;-) (compiler should then specify the behavior). But we agree that this kind of code should be avoided :-)

@Jarod42 'Unspecified', I knew I'd remember in the end

This line:
f(std::move(a), a.Something());

Can indeed constitute a use after move.
If your f is:
f(A a, int x) { ... }

Then the first argument will have to be either copied or moved into the parameter A a before invoking f. This means that the actual move can also take place before a.Something() is evaluated, causing a use after move.
It's worth nothing that if your f was e.g.:
f(A && a, int x) { ... }

Then you would be safe, because std::move itself is just a cast to rvalue ref which is what is expected for A && a, and therefore no move would actually take place at the stage of evaluating the arguments for f.


When exactly does an object cast with std::moved get moved?

It depends on how the reference returned by std::move() is being used.  std::move() itself doesn't do anything, it is just a type-cast, nothing more.  The actual move happens when something else receives that reference and decides to move the refered-to object's data.

For instance, does the following code constitute use after move?
f(std::move(a), a.Something())
Where f = f(A a, int x) and a is an instance of some class.

It CAN, but the order of evaluation of function parameters is not guaranteed.  std::move(a) MAY be evaluated first, or a.Something() MAY be evaluated first.  What is guaranteed is only that both parameters will have been fully evaluated before f() is actually entered.

I understand that std::move(a) may be evaluated before a.Something(), but when does the actual move itself occur?

Since the A a parameter is being passed into f() by value, a temporary object must be constructed for it. A move CAN happen if the return value of std::move() is used to move-construct that object, but only if the A(A&&) constructor is implemented (either implicitly by the compiler, or explicitly in A's code), and it actually performs a move.  Without that constructor, the object will be copy-constructed instead, and thus no move will happen.

It is worth mentioning that the initialization of the parameter is part of the argument evaluation and is, therefore, covered by statement "the order of evaluation of arguments is unspecified".

@j6t In fact, the standard itself doesn't say that the argument evaluation is not sequence, it says that the "parameter construction" is not sequenced, but that includes the computation of the expression you write on the corresponding argument's position expr.call#7: "The initialization of a parameter, including every associated value computation and side effect, is indeterminately sequenced with respect to that of any other parameter."
